# Iron Router to receive multi part form POST Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

How to make server side route using Iron Router that will accept POST Request to that given URL and receive the POST sent FILE/Image ? I am using Collection FS as Image Uploader and Grid FS to store the images what i want to do is receive the POST url using Iron Router and extract the file from the POST and use Collection FS or Any other image uploader to Upload that file. The reason i am using POST url rather than just template event handler to upload is, the text editor i am using is using POST submit to Server to upload images.

Answer (score 0):

After a little search it looks like [this package](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-methods) does the thing you want. HTTP methods is currently on [meteor's roadmap](https://trello.com/c/Lz07fBAm/7-server-side-rendering) and this looks like a good solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try busboy
https://github.com/mscdex/busboy

On iron router side

```
this.route('/upload', {
    where: 'server',
    method: 'POST',
    name:'upload',
    onBeforeAction: (function (req, res, next) {
        //busboy code here 
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ',    encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
        file.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
        });
        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
        });
    });
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        console.log('Done parsing form!');
        res.writeHead(303, { Connection: 'close', Location: '/' });
        res.end();
        next();
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
});
```